# Javascript wait for asynchronous call to finish

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, promise, async-await

I'm using a library which invokes a hook function whenever a new object is created:

```
// index.js
import Library from 'library';

Library.Hooks.UUID.register(function(context) {

    let newID = generateNewID(context); // async
    return newID;     // The library will use the return value of this hook function as the ID for the newly created object
})
```

The problem here, is that the hook function is synchronous, while my `generateNewID` function can be an asynchronous call out. (For what it's worth, I'm developing a Chrome extension and the background script is responsible for generating ID, which responds asynchronously to content script via `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.)

An obvious solution is to mark the hook function `async` and `await generateNewID(context)` but this will require converting the library to use a Promise-based hook mechanism.

What's a more elegant way to solve this problem without extensively rewriting the library?

Comment: You use callbacks or promises or events to communicate back asynchronously retrieved values.  Pick one and make `generateNewID()` and the `.register()` method use it.  There is no other shortcut.  You will have to architect appropriately for asynchronous options in a the hook function.  You will need some redesign - no way to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

> this will require converting the library to use a Promise-based hook mechanism.

Yes. There is no way around converting the library to support asynchronous hooks (or making `generateNewID` synchronous). Using promises to represent the asynchrony will be the easiest approach for that.